# Why is my wrapper div not cleared correctly

Tags: html, css, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/sWb7j/75/

I want to create a little chart which is scaling vertically.

Why is the chart not inside the yellow main div?

I thought I should clear after all 4 chart divs?

This is my code see also jsfiddle link above...

```
<div id="chart" style="background-color:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div id="replyTimes" style="background-color:red;width:100px;float:left;height:100%;">            
        <div style="height:100%;" >
            <div style="background-color:white;height:100%;">
                <div style="text-align:center;height:10%;"> </div>
                <div style="background-color:#ff33cc;text-align:center;height:40%;"> 5 min</div>
                <div style="background-color:#ff44cc;text-align:center;height:25%;"> 10 min</div>
                <div style="background-color:#ff55cc;text-align:center;height:25%;"> 15 min</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
               <div style="text-align:center;background-color:orange;width:100%;height:30px;"></div>
               <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#FAFAFA;width:100%;height:30px;">test</div>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="totalResponse" style="background-color:brown;width:100px;height:100%;float:left;">       
        <div style="background-color:pink;height:100%;">
            <div style="background-color:white;text-align:center;height:10%;"></div>
            <div style="background-color:gray;text-align:center;height:40%;">1</div>
            <div style="background-color:gray;text-align:center;height:25%;">2</div>
            <div style="background-color:gray;text-align:center;height:25%;">3</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="text-align:center;background-color:violet;width:100%;height:30px;">TOTAL</div>
            <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#FAFAFA;width:100%;height:30px;">10</div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <div id="responsesWrapper" style="background-color:blue;height:100%;float:left;">
        <div style="width:50px;height:100%;">  
            <div style="background-color:orange;height:100%;"> 
                <div style="background-color:#aa99cc;text-align:center;height:30%;">30</div>
                <div style="background-color:#aa66cc;text-align:center;height:40%;">40</div>
                <div style="background-color:#aa33cc;text-align:center;height:30%;">30</div>
            </div>           
            <div>
                <div style="text-align:center;background-color:pink;height:30px;">TF1</div>
                <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#FAFAFA;height:30px;">25</div>
            </div> 
        </div>    
    </div>
     <div id="responsesWrapper" style="background-color:blue;height:100%;float:left;">
        <div style="width:50px;height:100%;">  
            <div style="background-color:violet;height:100%;"> 
                <div style="background-color:#fdc;text-align:center;height:30%;">30</div>
                <div style="background-color:#fde;text-align:center;height:30%;">30</div>
                <div style="background-color:#fdf;text-align:center;height:40%;">40</div>
            </div>           
            <div>
                <div style="text-align:center;background-color:pink;height:30px;">TF1</div>
                <div style="text-align:center;background-color:#FAFAFA;height:30px;">25</div>
            </div> 
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I have created another sample with less markup but showing the same problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/sWb7j/132/

The layout is going out of the wrapper div.

Instead of float:left for the main divs I use display:inline-block so the divs are also left "floate" and and are treated like block elements so I can set a width.

How can I keep my vertically stretching/scaling divs and the layout is not going over the wrapper div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually is inside the yellow div, but you have a height of 100% on your wrapper

```
<div id="chart" style="background-color:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;">
```

this prevent the div from getting larger then 100%
If i change the height to auto you can see that it does wrap the content

```
<div id="chart" style="background-color:yellow;width:100%;height:auto;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWb7j/77/

Comment: but this changes my chart totally. I want it to scale vertically and consider the % sizes of the single divs.

Comment: Yes I have a height of 100% on the wrapper but also on all parent container like html and body. So how the wrapper div be overlapped?

Comment: @HelloWorld It's really simple man, the height on your wrapper is 100%, but the height of the elements in the wrapper extends 100%, thats why they float out. For example the left row you have 10% + 40% + 25% + 25% + 30px + 30px. This means it's more then 100% so it will float out of the container that is 100%.

Comment: yes its that simple, I have totally forgotten my fixed height divs. Thanks for the eye-opener.

Answer (score 0):

your clearing `<div>` is not valid HTML:

```
<div style="clear: left;" />
```

change to:

```
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

This may not answer your question, but keep in mind to use correct HTML to prevent further errors to happen.

Comment: This does not fix the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/sWb7j/85/ please remove your solution as its wrong!